# Possible to derive from an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance, memory, memory-management

Currently I have an class that contains an array and an integer.

I have millions of these objects, and would like to save memory by just having an array so I save 12 bytes for each object (by not having to allocate a class wrapper for each one). This will save a lot of memory.

Unfortunately, I need to store the integer as well. I was thinking about just storing it in the first index, but it is slightly messy. I was hoping I could just derive from an array and insert the int member in the subclass, but apparently that is disallowed by the compiler.

Are there any alternatives? I suppose I could just copy and paste the array class from the referencesource framework and add my property, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: Nope. Use composition instead of inheritance. If you want array-like syntax, implement an indexer.

Comment: The problem with composition is that an object is 12 bytes, so an object with an array is 24 bytes (because an array is a reference type as well), so composition is what I'm currently doing that I'd like an alternative to to save memory.

Comment: I take it that you can't just use `.Length` because your arrays might contain fewer elements than the declared array size?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean encoding the integer as the array length by having dummy elements? No that wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but you still can't do it. It's not really clear why you have "millions" of arrays; it's possible that a more thoughtful approach to the bigger picture would address that. You might also find that you could maintain the `int` values in one array, and references to the arrays themselves in another array, making a parallel data structure where objects are identified by index, not reference. In any case, while 12 bytes * millions is theoretically a lot of memory, so is "`int` + array" * millions. I.e. you already have a memory problem, even if you save 12 bytes per object.

Comment: I agree with Peter, but I also add that if you *know* the elements of the array are limited in value, you can store them all in a single `int` or `long` property, or two if there aren't enough bytes to represent the maximum value of each, or more, but the point is you can clamp it up. E.g. 4 bytes can be looked at a single value ranged from `int.Min` to `int.Max`, OR as 4 values ranging from 0 to 255 (or as 32 values ranging from 0 to 1...)

Comment: Each array must have a different int value. Parallel data structure wouldn't work either. Ok, I'll just store the data in the first element of an object array then. Thanks.

Comment: Taking for granted your assertion that using a class adds 12 extra bytes for each object, 12 million bytes is just 12 megabytes. I realize there are embedded systems with limited memory, but i would be shocked if you actually started hitting a memory limit because of an extra 12 MB.

Comment: One million items is just an example.

Answer (score 5):

You can't derive from an array (and "copy and paste the array class from the reference source framework" will likely not do you much good as arrays are very integrated into language/framework).

One option may be to use `struct` with integer and array - you'll get major pain to deal with `struct`, but if careful it will provide you exactly what you looking for (if your "integer value" is mutable or the array needs to change size - I'd strongly recommend forgetting you've seen such suggestion).